# What's the minimum hardware for CISCO IP phones?

Tags: networking, router, voip

I have a SOHO setup with about 8 computers/laptops/servers on a LAN and a regular ADSL internet connection over the phone line. There is no EPABX. Just a regular phone line (after the DSL splitter).

I'm using a Cisco ADSL Wifi Router WAG54G2 along with an D-Link 8-port switch to hook up all computers.

I chanced upon 4 free Cisco IP phones from another organization that was shutting down. These are slightly old. The model number is CP-7940G.

Whats the minimum hardware I require to hook up these phones on the LAN and the phone line. There are three ports behind the phones. I don't really require extension numbers, but I'd just like to use the IP phones instead of the regular phones.

There are three ports behind the phone.[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your 8 port switch gigabit?

Comment: Yes, it is. The Router itself has 4 ports as well.

Comment: I hope they included the power supply

Comment: [Cisco Unified IP Phone 7960G/7940G 
Administration Guide for Cisco Unified 
Communications 
Manager 7.0 (SCCP)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cuipph/7960g_7940g/7_0/sccp/english/administration/guide/TD-Book-Wrapper.pdf) would be a good place to start ...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek They support Power over Ethernet (PoE).

Comment: 10/100 SW is for ethernet in, 10/100 PC is ethernet out (if you want to use phone and PC on same ethernet port of a switch. Phone supports Power over Ethernet (PoE). AUX is for console access (so you can ignore this). I don't think it will work as a normal phone - it's VoiP only.

Comment: You'd need a POE capable switch or injector then

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hook it up to your phone line and run it locally you would need something to act as a PABX - In addition to the phones you will need a box which has an FXO port (to connect to the phone line), and PABX functionality - probably something running Asterisk PBX.   (You could have the FXO port separate or built into the device).

That said, that arguably defeats much of the purpose of VOIP phones in a home environment.   You should be able to hook the VOIP phones into your switch, and then configure them to work with a VOIP provider to make calls through the Internet rather then getting any expensive hardware.  You would probably want someone who provides "SIP VOIP services" - I don't know where about you are, and please don't consider it a recommendation - I've never used them - but if you are in America Vonage is well known - there are lots and lots of other providers though.

Comment: Btw A great option for a pbx for this environment is the grandstream ucm 6102, which is a good ip pbx at a low cost. It has two fxo ports.